# Is there an easy way to tell if a File stream has opened a directory instead of a file?

Tags: c++, file, directory

I'm making an HTTP server and when I get the path of the file they request I open it with the following:

```
returned_file = fopen(path, "r");
```

this (contrary to what I would think) succeeds even if the path is a directory.  Is there an easy way to check if the returned_file stream is a directory instead of a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the path points to a directory *before* you call fopen?

Comment: (Maybe this should have been a comment.)

Comment: of course I could, but that is basically what I'm asking, how would I check that?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on this, but I can't just check the path by seeing if a '/' is at the end to tell if it is a directory, because it isn't a requirement for a '/' to be at the end for it to be a directory

Comment: One of the two recommending fstat is a better choice. (I guess I'm so over-Cocoa'd that I've pushed some of the vanilla C stuff aside…)

Answer (score 4):

you can use fstat on the file descriptor returned by fopen.

Edit:
Here's and example program:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printISDir( FILE* fp, char const * name ) {
  int fdes = fileno(fp) ;
  struct stat fileInfo ;
  fstat(fdes, &fileInfo ) ;
  if ( S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode ) ) {
    printf("%s: I'm a dir!\n", name ) ;
  } else {
    printf("%s: I'm a file!\n", name ) ;
  }

}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  char const * directoryName = "/etc" ;
  char const * fileName = "/etc/hosts" ;

  FILE* dirFp = fopen(directoryName, "r") ;
  FILE* fileFp = fopen(fileName, "r") ;
  printISDir( dirFp, directoryName ) ;
  printISDir( fileFp, fileName ) ;
  fclose(dirFp) ;
  fclose(fileFp) ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on the other answers, you can call fstat on the returned file descriptor and check the `st_mode` for the `S_IFDIR` bit.  The S_ISDIR helper macro is helpful:

```
  #include <sys/stat.h>
```

...

```
  FILE* f = fopen(path, "r");

  struct stat buf;
  if (fstat(fileno(f), &buf) == -1) {
    perror("fstat");
  } else {
    if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
      printf("is directory\n");
    } else {
      printf("not directory\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) from <sys/stat.h> can also be used

Answer (score 0):

Use stat() on the file name before you open it, or fstat() the file descriptor fileno(returned_file).

Comment: I tried using stat and it returns a struct stat, now using that structure how do I determine if it is a directory?

Comment: Don't use stat, use fstat. You always need to check after you opened it to avoid the race condition where it was a file when you checked it, but was deleted and turned into a directory before your open completed.